# Injecting $location into Angular config causes 'Unkown Provider' error

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

This is the first time I've tried using Angular with Wordpress. I want to inject `$location` into the `config` module so I can use it like this:

```
app = angular.module 'app', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute' ]
app.config [ '$routeProvider', '$location', ( $routeProvider, $location )->

    $location.hasPrefix '!'
    $location.html5Mode true

]
```

Unfortunately, using `$location` or `$locationProvider` with `config` is causing an Unknown Provider error. I've included all necessary dependencies ie. `angular-route.min.js`, however, it's still not resolving properly.

If I remove `$location` it works.

```
app = angular.module 'app', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute' ]
app.config [ '$routeProvider', ( $routeProvider )->

    # ROUTES 

]
```

## EDIT

If I replace `$location` with `$locationProvider` I get `Failed to instantiate module app due to: TypeError: Object # has no method 'hasPrefix'`

Comment: This might help you: [Inject service in app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937267/inject-service-in-app-config).

Comment: I think you can only inject providers in `config` and only services in `app.run`

Comment: I'm still receiving and error if I use `$locationProvider` instead of `$location`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was a simple typo.

`$location.hasPrefix('!');`

should be

`$location.hashPrefix('!');`

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine if you use the name `$locationProvider` as the name of the injectable.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8h60Is?p=preview).

And the js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { // provider-injector
    $locationProvider.hasPrefix = '!';
    $locationProvider.html5Mode = true;
  });
```

For reference from Docs:

> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.

Comment: Hmm, `$location` or `$locationProvider` both work, if I assign them like `$locationProvider.html5Mode = true;`, but not if I use the method `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642634/angular-location-hash-prefix